# TextToSpeech is not working properly in Service class

Tags: android

Hello everone i am using texttospeech in my project and i have tried this code in activity class it working fine but in service class its not working fine
I am using text to speech in my project but it is throwing this error. Can anyone tell please what i must do so that it work...

Code....

```
public class CallerService extends Service implements
    TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

String number;

private TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

}

@Override
@Deprecated
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    number = intent.getStringExtra("phnumber");

    fetchContacts();
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) 
     {
             tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
     } 
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();

}

public void fetchContacts() {
tts.speak("kd arjit", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,
                                    null);}
}
}
```

Logcat is...

```
04-07 12:27:00.028: I/TextToSpeech.java(5948): initTts() successfully bound to service
04-07 12:27:01.038: D/dalvikvm(5948): GC_EXPLICIT freed 83K, 45% free 3123K/5639K, `external 743K/1036K, paused 54ms
04-07 12:27:02.158: I/Contact Name:(5948): kd arjit
04-07 12:27:02.168: I/TextToSpeech.java - speak(5948): speak text of length 8
04-07 12:27:02.168: E/TextToSpeech.java - speak(5948): service isn't started
04-07 12:27:02.298: D/dalvikvm(5948): GC_CONCURRENT freed 375K, 48% free 3142K/5959K, external 758K/1036K, paused 2ms+4ms
04-07 12:27:02.308: W/CursorWrapperInner(5948): Cursor finalized without prior close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logcat does not really show any errors, but the problem is that you call:

```
 fetchContacts();
```

before :

```
 public void onInit(int status)
```

is executed with success. You are allowed to call `tts.speak` only after successfull `onInit` callback is executed. So you should move your `fetchContacts();` inside `onInit`.